# abstract contract getting deployed instead of the main contract on truffle migrate

Tags: truffle, abstract

I'm building a project which consists of two .sol files -> A.sol and B.sol. Now, 
A.sol contains an abstract contract definition of B, among other things, like this:

```
Contract B {
  function fnB() public;
}
```

similarly B.sol contains an abstract contract definition of A:

```
Contract A {
  function fnA() public;
}
```

This is been designed such to attain a certain 'message passing' between the two contracts. There is no inheritance between these two contracts, as the abstract contracts are being used for composition. Now the problem is, while using truffle, the '2_deploy_contracts.js' file imports artifacts for both using their contract name (instead of the .sol file name). An error is being thrown because of that since the truffle migrate command is considering the respective abstract contracts instead of the main contracts. Is there a workaround for this? The exact error thrown by 'truffle migrate' command is this:

```
"A" is an abstract contract or an interface and cannot be deployed.
   * Import abstractions into the '.sol' file that uses them instead of deploying them separately.
   * Contracts that inherit an abstraction must implement all its method signatures exactly.
   * A contract that only implements part of an inherited abstraction is also considered abstract.
    at Deployer._preFlightCheck
```

The deploy js file looks something like this:

```
var A = artifacts.require("A");
var B = artifacts.require("B");

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {


    if(network == "ganache") {
        deployer.deploy(A, {gas:400000})
            .then(function(receipt) {
                return deployer.deploy(B, A.address, {from:accounts[0], gas:400000});
            })
            .catch(function(e){
                console.log(e);
            });   }};
```

Comment: Share your migration scripts please (or at least the 2nd one - `2_deploy_contracts.js`).

Comment: BTW, you should use interfaces there, not contracts.

Comment: `code` var A = artifacts.require("A");
var B = artifacts.require("B");

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {


    if(network == "ganache") {
        deployer.deploy(A, {gas:400000})
            .then(function(receipt) {
                return deployer.deploy(B, A.address, {from:accounts[0], gas:400000});
            })
            .catch(function(e){
                console.log(e);
            });

            

    }
  
};`code`

Comment: Good, now share your contracts as well please.

Comment: The problem here (I believe) is that var A is catching the abstract contract A residing in B, and var B is catching the abstract contract B residing in A, instead of taking the corresponding main definitions.

Comment: Like I said - share your Solidity code. Sounds like one of your contracts does not implement all the functions that it should implement (leaving some of them abstract).

Comment: there is only one function mentioned in both of the abstract contracts and they are both being called inside the main contracts. I am not using the abstract contracts for inheritance, but for composition. 

I cannot share the solidity code since it is too big.

Comment: Well share the relevant information required for reproducing this problem, otherwise no one here will be able to refer to it. From what you've shared, it looks like both contracts are abstract, and therefore neither one of them can be deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved by giving a different contract name for the constituent abstract contracts in the following manner:

```
    Contract BInterface {
  function fnB() public;
}

Contract A {
... codes for contract A ...
... codes for contract A ...

BInterface private bInterface;
bInterface = new bInterface(<address of B>);
}
```

also the same setup for contract B:

```
Contract AInterface {
      function fnA() public;
    }

    Contract B {
    ... codes for contract B ...
    ... codes for contract B ...

    AInterface private aInterface;
    aInterface = new aInterface(<address of A>);
    }
```

now there is no collision between the names of abstract contract and the main contracts.